How does reduction of double bond in alpha,beta unsaturated aldehyde or ketone occur using NaBH4?
I was going through some problems on reduction using NaBH4 and came across the fact that when there is a conjugated double bond with the carbonyl group, NaBH4 gives both saturated as well as unsaturated alcohol. Could anyone share the mechanism for the reduction of double bond in this case?

This question has been answered here very well by Phillip, and I would encourage you to read it: Why does NaBH4 reduce double bonds conjugated to carbonyl groups, while LiAlH4 does not?
A few additional important things to note when dealing with conjugated carbonyls: theoretically, you expect 3 products from the reaction, an unsaturated alcohol 1, a saturated alcohol 2, and the saturated carbonyl 3. The formation of saturated alcohols is a two-step process where 2 equivalents of $\text{NaBH}_4$ react with 1 of the starting conjugated carbonyl, with the first step being the reduction of the double bond, leaving behind an aldehyde or ketone, both of which are subject to reduction by borohydride in scheme 1. Why the unsaturated alcohol 1 forms is a simple carbonyl reduction by sodium borohydride, which is the second half of scheme 1, just with the double bond still in place. The third product, the saturated carbonyl 3, is the first half of scheme 1. Note the enolate resonance forms playing a key role here.
Why this reduction happens is in the previous answer. Essentially, the β carbon satisfies all the requirements to act as a soft Lewis acid. The species is big (spread over the double bond), polarizable (the π cloud can be attracted towards something, especially at the β carbon; ref. resonant structures of vinyl carbonyls), and has a low charge state. Soft centres will interact with soft nucleophiles (like hydride, with a large ionic radius, which according to some sources, is close to 140pm in radius; easily polarizable). This creates the enolate and can either react further or re-form a carbonyl.


Practically, you would expect the saturated alcohol (2) to be your major product if no other conditions were in place. The 1,4-reduction is favored, resulting in the saturated carbonyl, and carbonyls are then incredibly prone to borohydride reductions. Consequently, you would get almost none of 3. If you wanted selectivity for the 1,2-reduction (scheme 2 from Wikipedia) to form 1, you would need to use a strong Lewis acid -- most commonly used in this case is $\text{CeCl}_3$ in methanol, which is called the Luche reduction, though keep in mind this only works for ketones, not aldehydes. If you wanted just the double bond to be reduced, there are some interesting systems of borohydride and Pd/C and therefore get just product 3, though I am unsure of how this works and requires more research.

